# how to run pyspark as py script

Tags: python, apache-spark

i tried to run this code as a python script

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local')

from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])  #can set first param to '/'
def toyFunction():
    return 'HELLO WORLD'

if __name__ == '__main_':
    app.run(port=8080)    #note set to 8080!
```

then what this came out.

> D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7>python app.py Using Spark's
>   default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust logging level use
>   sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
>   18/03/21 14:28:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable
>
> D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7>SUCCESS: The process with PID
>   7656 (child process of PID 3876) has been terminated. SUCCESS: The
>   process with PID 3876 (child process of PID 4436) has been
>   terminated.SUCCESS: The process with PID 4436 (child process of PID
>   1148) has been terminated.

any solution?

- Also tried spark-submit but an error also appeared which I posted here [Pyspark in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390292/pyspark-in-flask?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I also read in the post [How to run a script in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028919/how-to-run-a-script-in-pyspark)

that running python applications through pyspark is not supported as of Spark 2.0.  I am using 2.2.0.  one of the solutions was by another person

pyspark 2.0 and later execute script file in environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP, so you can run:

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=code.py pyspark
```

Compared to spark-submit answer this is useful for running initialization code before using the interactive pyspark shell.

but I do not understand how to do that? can anyone guide me? thank you

Comment: I think duplicated question. [how-to-run-a-script-in-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028919/how-to-run-a-script-in-pyspark)

Comment: i also tried ./bin/spark-submit app.py still didnt work.  the error I got is posted here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390292/pyspark-in-flask?noredirect=1#comment85783539_49390292

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a script in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028919/how-to-run-a-script-in-pyspark)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390292/pyspark-in-flask?noredirect=1&lq=1